# Get the source of the URL entered in the edit text

Tags: android

I have a requirement where in I have to get the Source of the URL address which is entered in the edit Text. Am able to get the source file of the URL which is hard coded in the HTTPGET request. The code is as below..

```
public String getHtml() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpGet httpGet = new  HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);


    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
          response.getEntity().getContent()
        )
      );

    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
      result += line + "\n"; 
    Log.d("result","="+result);

    }

    return result;

}
```

And saving it in the file like:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
            File file = new File(etPath.getText().toString());
            FileWriter writer=null;
            try
            {
                writer = new FileWriter(file);

                /** Saving the contents to the file*/
                writer.write(getHtml());

                /** Closing the writer object */
                writer.close();


                /** Getting sharedpreferences object to store the path of last saved file */
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

                /** Setting the last saved file's path in the shared preference */
                editor.putString("fpath", file.getPath());

                /** Save the path to the shared preference */
                editor.commit();

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Successfully saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
```

This method is properly returning the source of google.com.
But I need to do something like this:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new  HttpGet(etContent.getText().toString());
```

Where etContent is the edit text in which the URL is being entered.
But when I execute this statement, its crashing.

I need to extract the source of the URL enterd in the edit text.I don't intend to use async task. Please help me out guys.

Please post some code in support. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the poroblem myself. The problem was I was not appending http:// while entering the URL. Its working fine now. Thanks all :-)